# Cannot connect to SAP HANA Express DB using eclipse studio

Tags: database, eclipse-plugin, hana

I am new to SAP HANA database. I have successfully hosted the SAP HANA express database on cloud server. I have created a database and I am able to query it for the CLI.

However I have trouble connecting it from eclipse have spent two days on the same.

I am following https://developers.sap.com/india/tutorials/hxe-howto-eclipse.html tutorial.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Please Note :

1. I am able to connect to server using RDP and putty so the IP address is correct
2. I have started the database using command:

   ```
   hdbsql -i 90 -d HXE -u SYSTEM -p SAPhxe123
   ```
3. why is eclipse taking port 39015 by default in last screenshot? is this the issue or can we change this.

Any help here would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is this a docker installation? Or the image from the marketplace on Azure?

Comment: I don't know about Ether's case @LuciaS but I installed the HXE using AWS Marketplace including advanced applications

Comment: @Ether What is your release of Eclipse? I had  Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9) and installed SAP related perspectives from  https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/2018-09

Comment: Seeing the same issue and none of the answer posted works

Answer (score 1):

Remove the port and just keep HXE for the tenant.

39015 is the right one for the first tenant in an AWS or Azure VM (39017 is for Docker).

Try connecting to the system database first. If that works but the tenant doesn't, check this: https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/hxe-gcp-eclipse-tenant-connect.html

If that doesn't work: https://blogs.sap.com/2018/02/24/troubleshooting-connection-problems-for-hana-express/

Unless you explicitly closed port 22, ping should respond.

Also a reminder that HANA studio is part of a set of deprecated tools so if you are looking to learn native development, I would recommend going for XS advanced.

Comment: Hi Lucia, for my case I installed the HXE on AWS using AWS Marketplace. I subscribed Hana Express Edition with Advanced Applications. I can connect to Web IDE from a web browser on my local computer. Within Web IDE, using Database Explorer I can connect to System database and to HXE database on this multitenant HXE. In connection details, I see 39013 (not 39015). I added screenshots at https://github.com/SAPDocuments/Tutorials/issues/3242

Comment: 39013 is for the system database. In the screenshots you say you want to connect to the HXE tenant database. Anyways, the port is irrelevant in that case. If you specify the name of the database you should be able to connect. If you scenario is different formt he orignal question you should create a different question.

Also, our GitHub repository is not meant to provide support .

Comment: Hi Lucia, could you please refer to screen recording at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8EbfR6xGj5o    Maybe I can show it better via this record

Comment: I checked and I'm not having this problem with Eclipse Photon. Is that 2018-09? Have you tried a different version?

Comment: Version is 2018-09 . Thank you Lucia, I'll try an other version and inform you soon

Answer (score 0):

Could you please refer to following document: https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/mlb-hxe-tools-sql-eclipse.html

There the tenant database connection is created as follows

The host server (IP) is maintained in hosts file

Additionally the tenant db is only provided as HXE without port number

[image]

Comment: tried with the host file same issue , i have hosted the db on microsoft azure machine , by default it does not allow ping to the IP directly due to security reasons.. However i am able to connect using RDP and putty using same IP   . Also the docker command used to start the database uses port 39017 .. however i see eclipse is always taking port 39015.. still stuck

Comment: I am also testing the same case on my mac and stuck at the same point

Answer (score 0):

If you running the HANA server as a container.

1. Go in to the container "docker exec -it  bash
2. HDB info
3. What is the port that you can connect to (If the Port is 39041 for example)
4. Rerun your container mapping your docker run command with -p:. That is (-p 3901:39015).

Essentially what is broken is that the port Eclipse HANA studio is trying to connect to is not mapped to the HANA port that is listening on.

You have to map the PORT that HANA is listening to Host PORT 39015.

If this is a cloud env you have to do the appropriate port forwarding.

Tested this and it works now.

Answer (score -1):

For tenant database, I think it is enough to use HXE
Did you try to change the host name by adding the port information after IP address?

Comment: i tried only HXE but same issue ,also if i try to add port after IP then the address in the last image becomes 104.211.157.182:39017:39015

Answer (score -1):

When your HXE instance was created on AWS, did you assigned it the default security group or did create one based on "Seller settings"?

This is really important because without this custom security group you won't be able to access your instance from the outside world.

Please refer to the following tutorial for more details: https://developers.sap.com/canada/tutorials/hxe-aws-setup.html